# is the sentence "great business are built one productive person at a time" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I read this sentence on the book :

> great business are built one productive person at a time

It makes me wonder how a noun could come directly after "are built". In my view, some preposition needs to come between "built" and "one".  Is that sentence grammatically wrong or is it just some kind of literary expression? what does the author try to tell us eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Plural - eg multiple businesses:
Great businesses are built one productive person at a time

Singular - refers to 'business' as a noun:
Great business is built one productive person at a time.

Comment: I know Great business is a plural form. I just find that sentence unnatural for that reason above.